# Limit `Insert Sitecore Link` Locations in the RTE (Sitecore)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, rte

I am looking to do something similar to the `Insert Sitecore Link` as I can with, for example, `Image` fields in which I can add a `Source` in order to limit from what directories an Image can be picked from. I want to be able to limit what items the content editor can link to as it currently shows the whole Sitecore database when `Insert Sitecore Link` is clicked.

Comment: Are talking about a Link field (DropLink, InternalLink etc...) or the `Insert Sitecore Link` button in the Rich Text Editor?

Comment: @RichardSeal in the Rich Text Editor I think, according to the title.

Comment: @RichardSeal In the RTE.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd probably go about doing this would be to create a custom button for the RTE toolbar and implement your own insert sitecore link functionality (possibly based on the existing functionality).

See https://markstiles.net/Blog/2011/02/05/adding-button-to-rich-text-editor.aspx for a quick primer on how to achieve this.